# Cannot restart apache on Centos 7

Tags: centos, firewall, iptables, http, localhost

I cannot restart HTTPD on Centos 7. When I try to run the command it shows this error below. How can I overcome this?

```
-- 
-- Unit session-735.scope has begun starting up.
Apr 12 15:33:01 localhost.localdomain CROND[21294]: (system1) CMD (/usr/bin/test.sh)
Apr 12 15:33:09 localhost.localdomain libvirtd[24538]: operation failed: filter 'allow-arp' already exists with uuid 9ede09e5-7eee-4664-afd6-0fa3058ea
Apr 12 15:33:09 localhost.localdomain libvirtd[24538]: operation failed: filter 'allow-dhcp-server' already exists with uuid cae0426f-1586-4445-b84d-3
Apr 12 15:33:09 localhost.localdomain libvirtd[24538]: operation failed: filter 'allow-dhcp' already exists with uuid ce9f6a68-91dc-46a3-9a63-ea3dbae4
Apr 12 15:33:09 localhost.localdomain libvirtd[24538]: operation failed: filter 'allow-incoming-ipv4' already exists with uuid e5073a56-6440-4d21-a957
Apr 12 15:33:09 localhost.localdomain libvirtd[24538]: operation failed: filter 'allow-ipv4' already exists with uuid c6f407a3-7234-4531-97eb-644639e9
Apr 12 15:33:09 localhost.localdomain libvirtd[24538]: operation failed: filter 'clean-traffic' already exists with uuid 3b3dea02-6ab9-4694-9e42-a9f94
Apr 12 15:33:09 localhost.localdomain libvirtd[24538]: operation failed: filter 'no-arp-ip-spoofing' already exists with uuid ba673b60-e987-449e-ba56-
Apr 12 15:33:09 localhost.localdomain libvirtd[24538]: operation failed: filter 'no-arp-mac-spoofing' already exists with uuid a96cb8f8-e151-4bf1-8cc1
Apr 12 15:33:09 localhost.localdomain libvirtd[24538]: operation failed: filter 'no-arp-spoofing' already exists with uuid 53d68a77-494e-4258-8997-ed0
Apr 12 15:33:09 localhost.localdomain libvirtd[24538]: operation failed: filter 'no-ip-multicast' already exists with uuid be43497d-562d-464b-87ad-fdb
Apr 12 15:33:09 localhost.localdomain libvirtd[24538]: operation failed: filter 'no-ip-spoofing' already exists with uuid 95117e28-36a7-40ae-8335-c1af
Apr 12 15:33:09 localhost.localdomain libvirtd[24538]: operation failed: filter 'no-mac-broadcast' already exists with uuid 821df32b-d29b-47ee-90ed-f3
Apr 12 15:33:09 localhost.localdomain libvirtd[24538]: operation failed: filter 'no-mac-spoofing' already exists with uuid 283f0698-79e6-4b19-9f91-9e7
Apr 12 15:33:09 localhost.localdomain libvirtd[24538]: operation failed: filter 'no-other-l2-traffic' already exists with uuid 4ef5b4e6-85ae-4f01-a8d5
Apr 12 15:33:09 localhost.localdomain libvirtd[24538]: operation failed: filter 'no-other-rarp-traffic' already exists with uuid bd40fb4d-81fa-4e48-99
Apr 12 15:33:09 localhost.localdomain libvirtd[24538]: operation failed: filter 'qemu-announce-self-rarp' already exists with uuid e67ed07a-672f-4c79-
Apr 12 15:33:09 localhost.localdomain libvirtd[24538]: operation failed: filter 'qemu-announce-self' already exists with uuid 49448b0f-1536-4995-b756-
Apr 12 15:33:16 localhost.localdomain polkitd[875]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:21774:2012579 (system bus name :1.1728 [/usr/bin/
Apr 12 15:33:16 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit httpd.service has begun starting up.
Apr 12 15:33:16 localhost.localdomain httpd[21789]: AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using local
Apr 12 15:33:16 localhost.localdomain httpd[21789]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
Apr 12 15:33:16 localhost.localdomain httpd[21789]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
Apr 12 15:33:16 localhost.localdomain httpd[21789]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Apr 12 15:33:16 localhost.localdomain httpd[21789]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Apr 12 15:33:16 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 12 15:33:16 localhost.localdomain kill[21805]: kill: cannot find process ""
Apr 12 15:33:16 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 12 15:33:16 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit httpd.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Apr 12 15:33:16 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Apr 12 15:33:16 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Apr 12 15:33:17 localhost.localdomain polkitd[875]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:21774:2012579 (system bus name :1.1728, object 
Apr 12 15:33:35 localhost.localdomain google-chrome.desktop[5201]: LaunchProcess: failed to execvp:
Apr 12 15:33:35 localhost.localdomain google-chrome.desktop[5201]: /opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox
Apr 12 15:33:40 localhost.localdomain google-chrome.desktop[5201]: Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
Apr 12 15:34:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Session 736 of user system1.
-- Subject: Unit session-736.scope has finished start-up
```

Comment: Looks like an IP Config issue - has the machine got a working IP address and valid name?

Answer (score 0):

It's trying to bind to

> 0.0.0.0:80
>
> and
>
> [::]:80

and it can't.

Do `netstat -punta | grep LISTEN`, if you can see port 80 on the output, get the pid and `kill` the process and the restart `httpd`